# MongoDB - How to show all items in a collection on dashboard on the website

Tags: mongodb, collections

When I want to list all the items in a Collection in my profile on the MongoDB website, it usually displays just one item and writes something like QUERY RESULTS 5-5 OF MANY above it (although there are 10 items in it), so I have to use arrows to cycle through the items. It's slowing me down when I want to change something about all the items, like maybe add a parameter or change the values.
Is there a way to get rid of that and see more items at the same time, listed in a column so I can edit them faster?

Comment: Clarify what the MongoDB website means.   Do you mean MongoDB Compass?

Comment: It's when I sign into my profile at mongodb.com, then in the Atlas tab.